# XML Loading in flash not working on facebook

Tags: xml, flash, facebook

I have a flash file which calls up a url say http://test.com/createXML/ which is caught and used up by a python/django code and it creates and redirects to an XML. which is loaded by flash, to get values from the database.

The setup works fine when outside facebook, but as soon as I put the setup in facebook, it stops loading the XML completely.

Any clues?

Fahim.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an appropriate `crossdomain.xml` file in the `test.com` domain (where the xml is hosted)? If not, add a  `crossdomain.xml` file at the root of the server that looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <!-- set the domain attr to appropriate value or 
     just * if you are fine with it -->
  <allow-access-from domain="*.facebook.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: The problem is that I am access the data through http://apps.facebook.com not my own server and apps.facebook.com does not provide a crossdomain.xml